# Telerik Radgrid : Suddenly appear down arrow and another simbol on selected row

Tags: checkbox, telerik, row, radgrid, checked

I have a problem in telerik radgrid.

I just checked the second row and then appear suddenly a down arrow when mouse out of second row.

This the code

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgManagmentByCenter" runat="server" Width="330px" GridLines="None"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="false" SkinID="Tower" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" ShowHeader="true"
                            OnItemCreated="RadGrid1_ItemCreated"
                            OnPreRender="RadGrid1_PreRender" > 


                          <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true" >
                                <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true"   />
                            </ClientSettings>
                            <MasterTableView Width="100%" ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="true" DataKeyNames="Id" >
                                <Columns>

                                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="CheckBoxTemplateColumn" >
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="headerChk" OnCheckedChanged="ToggleSelectedState" AutoPostBack="True"
                                            runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate >
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="rowChk" OnCheckedChanged="ToggleRowSelection" AutoPostBack="True"
                                            runat="server" ></asp:CheckBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                                    <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName="ClientSelectColumn" DataTextField="Id" Display="false" />
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Id" UniqueName="Id" Display="false">
                                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" SortExpression="Name" UniqueName="Name"
                                        HeaderText="" meta:resourcekey="Name">
                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                        <ItemStyle Width="90%" HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="True" />
                                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Center.Name" SortExpression="Center" UniqueName="Center"
                                        HeaderText="" meta:resourcekey="Center" Visible="false" >
                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                        <ItemStyle Width="35%" HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="True"  />
                                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                </Columns>
                            </MasterTableView>
                        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

[See the problem here - Open with Google Chrome](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2QXP7VNInnzVm1YaFhDaVJoaUE/edit)

Comment: If you have not solved the problem yet, please post also the cs code, I will try to replicate the issue. On which version are you with Telerik?

Comment: I solved the problem. That was because the SkinID have some lines about event mouse out. Just clean those lines. That's all. Thanks.